# My Rails console session went wrong and now my rspec tests fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-console

I am using Postgres 9.1, Rails 3.1.3 and Ruby 1.9.3.

I tried some things out in `rails console --sandbox` and then I ventured to `rails console`.
On entering `Employee.create!(a whole lot of data)`, I got some errors, most of them to do with `not null` constraints.

I quickly left the console and using `pgadmin3` checked to see if I had changed the database but there was no data so I felt confident that my tests would still pass. Unfortunately, my `rspec` test now fails and I am not sure where the conflicting data is.

Hopefully someone reading this has an idea or suggestion of how I can undo the entry I entered in my console session, which unfortunately was not the `--sandbox` session.

I did manage to kill the phantom server which I found through `lsof | grep 3000`.

Thanks for any help, suggestions or pointers you can spare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you play in the console, you're in the development environment, I don't think there is a way that it conflicts with your tests which are run in the test env.
Plus, the tests should not rely on any existant data, since the test database is erased each time you run your tests.

Try to run `rake db:test:prepare` and run your tests.

Comment: Thanks Robin, when I grow up I want to be able to reason like you.

Comment: ;) In this case it's not really about reasoning, you just need a little bit of experience :)